# How do I write this matrix?

Tags: matrix, programming

The following code gives 20 data as output.

[image]

How can I make a 5*4 matrix by that data list?

Comment: Check out `Table`, and don't forget to capitalize `Sin` and `Cos`.

Comment: Please post code in code blocks in the future. This is not copyable. I think this will answer all your questions: [Why avoid `For`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12)

Comment: It is edited @Szabolcs

Comment: Hi a-b, when Szabolcs asks for code, he means text that can be copy-pasted. The only way we can fix problems is if we can reproduce them!

Comment: Please post the code as text (not an image).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a starting point without the For loops:

```
Clear@f; 
f[i_, j_] /; OddQ[j] := c[i, j]; 
f[i_, j_] /; EvenQ[j] := s[i, j]; 

n1 = 2; 
res = Table[f[i, j], {i, -n1, n1}, {j, 1, 2*n1}]; 

(* Note MatrixForm is for presentation, not for computations *)
    res // MatrixForm
```

[image]

You can then enter your definition of c and s

Comment: Oh please, leave away `MatrixForm`. It is the cause for so many desperate questions on this forum... (still +1).

Comment: Good point! I added a comment above to separate the calculated result from the presentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 2;
Table[
 If[OddQ[j],
  Cos[2. Pi i j/(2 n + 1)],
  Sin[2. Pi i j/(2 n + 1)]
  ],
 {i, -n, n}, {j, 1, 2 n}
 ]
```

Comment: +1 Or slightly shorter `Table[If[OddQ[j], Cos, Sin][2. Pi i j/(2 n + 1)], {i, -n, n}, {j, 
  2 n}]`